# Flex linechart advanced tutorial

Tags: apache-flex

I need to build a sales graph for a company and I am going to need to really customize the LineChart in Flex. Can anyone point me to a tutorial or even a book that gives exhaustive coverage of the LineChart in Flex?

**UPDATE**
Thank you guys for your answers but I am looking for an in-depth full coverage of everything you can do with the LineChart. I am trying to build a custom one and I am having trouble customizing it in further then those tutorials explain. I want something that will give me a deep understanding of how they work so I can intelligently program them instead of programming by permutation.

Comment: did you ever have much luck with this? I cant find much either, and its been a year and a half! Any links you could share?

Answer (score 0):

First check out Adobe's [LineChart](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_08.html) tutorial and [Chart formatting](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/charts_formatting_05.html) tutorial. Since you have not specified the exact details, I'd suggest you look around the blogs a bit. A good start would be [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/11/15/displaying-grid-lines-in-a-flex-linechart-control/).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [flexexamples](http://blog.flexexamples.com/). This has tonnes of examples for all of the types of charts.